# How to update file in FileProvider?

Tags: android

Cannot find any document how to update file or insert file to FileProvider.

Any attempt ends with a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.MyApp.fileprovider",
                    file);

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("my_images", byteArray);
getContentResolver().update(photoURI,values,null,null);
```

--

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No external updates                                                                   
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.update(FileProvider.java:503)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:368)
at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1415)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot find any document how to update file or insert file to FileProvider.

You don't. You create or update *files*, using ordinary Java file I/O. `FileProvider` merely makes them available as needed to third-party apps.

In your particular case, write the `byteArray` to `file` using a `FileOutputStream`, assuming that `file` is the file that you want to create or update.